# is the $\arcsin$ of a transcendental number, algebraic?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

It's know that $\sin a$ is a transcendental $t$ if $a \neq 0$ and algebraic. So

$\sin a = t$

This would imply

$\arcsin(t) = a$

And this question can be done for all inverse trigonometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^i$ is transcendental by the Gelfond-Schneider theorem, so
$\sin(\ln(2)) = \frac{2^{i} - 1/2^{i}}{2i}$ is transcendental; $\ln(2)$ is  transcendental by Lindemann's theorem.  Thus $x = \sin(\ln(2))$, $\arcsin(x) = \ln(2)$ is an example where $x$ and $\arcsin(x)$ are both transcendental.

Answer (score 4):

No. The set of algebraic numbers is [countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489186/prove-that-the-set-of-all-algebraic-numbers-is-countable), while the set of transcendental numbers is not. Hence, there is at least one (and actually uncountable many!) transcendental numbers $\alpha$ for which $\sin^{-1} \alpha$ is also transcendental. This follows, e.g. from the continuity and monotonicity of the arcsin function.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to take the converse of the implication, which is not valid.  It is true that if $a \neq 0$ is algebraic, then $\sin a$ is transcendental.  However, there are transcendental $t$ such that $\arcsin t$ is also transcendental.  As there are uncountably many transcendental numbers and only countably many algebraic numbers, most transcendental numbers (less than $1$ in absolute value) have transcendental $\arcsin$.  It is hard to prove specific numbers transcendental.  I would be "sure" that $\arcsin \frac e{10}$ is transcendental, but I don't have an approach to prove it.